# designing a controller for an unstable plant?

Tags: control-theory

How do would anyone make a controller for a system which is $G(s) = \frac{(s-2)}{(s-1)(s-6)}$

I do not see how this system can ever become stable, without using pole/zero cancelation.

So how should i make this system stable??

Comment: What is the dynamics and what is the control objective?

Comment: The control objective is just to make it stable. 
it's a SISO systems for which BIBO stability is wanted.